# Can we use different run-time in Azure Data Factory v2 (ADFv2) Copy Activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have copy activity, where source is Oracle on premises connected through Self-hosted IR and destination is Microsoft Synapse connected via Azure Run-time. These run-time is defined in connections (Linked Services).

But while execution pipeline is using Self Hosted Run-time through-out and overriding the run-time of Azure Synapse. And because of that connection is failing.

Is this default behavior? Can't I run pipeline with 2 different run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @wBob but I am sorry that is not true, I found the answer at Microsoft documentation.

**Copying between a cloud data source and a data source in private network**: if either source or sink linked service points to a self-hosted IR, the copy activity is executed on that self-hosted Integration Runtime.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#determining-which-ir-to-use

Comment: You say "connection is failing" - can you provide a specific error message?

Comment: This is right! I faced similar issue so had to use the managed virtual network IR.

Answer (score 0):

Integration runtimes are defined at the linked service level.  So you should have a linked service definition for your Oracle database and a separate linked service definition for your Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly known as Azure SQL Data Warehouse).  So you can specify different integration runtimes, eg here's an example:

[image: Synapse linked service]

NB Azure Synapse Analytics is using the Autoresolve runtime and does not need a self-hosted integration runtime (SHIR) as it is a native PaaS service.  Are you getting a specific error?  If so, please post details.